# Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter

I have integrated my flutter app with firebase messaging and successfully received  notifications and all working fine, but now when i tried to run the project again it shows the error and when i send a notification to the device, it stops.

the error

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 8359): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359): Process: com.tapfy.me, PID: 8359
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4204)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4192)
E/AndroidRuntime( 8359):    ... 8 more
I/Process ( 8359): Sending signal. PID: 8359 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

create new Application class

```
class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
}

override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
    io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
}
```

}

change your Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".Application"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter Android Embedding V2 (Flutter Version >= 1.12) then no additional integration steps are required. But for V1 you need to edit.

Application class:

```
// ...
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements 
PluginRegistrantCallback {
  // ...
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService
              .setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Android Manifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:name=".Application"
    ...
```

[Link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview) for official documentation.